# Google Chrome is only showing white website, is not responding and uses all CPU

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04, white-screen

For the last couple of days I have the following problem with google chrome:

When I start chrome, it opens the normal window but the web page is only a white page. I can not use the menu to open the settings or use chrome://settings in the address field to open the settings. Also chrome eats up all my cpu.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on my XPS 13 - 9310.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I found the setting `--enable-logging` on some pages and started chrome with this flag. It produces the following log file:

```
$ batcat -p .config/google-chrome/chrome_debug.log
[1367400:1367458:1030/093208.127999:WARNING:external_pref_loader.cc(300)] You are using an old-style extension deployment method (external_extensions.json), which will soon be deprecated. (see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)
[1367400:1367400:1030/093208.164084:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[1367449:1367449:1030/093208.190008:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(380)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[1367400:1367400:1030/093223.586917:WARNING:controller_impl.cc(1190)] Background download complete, client: 6, completion type: 0, file size:265060
[1367400:1367400:1030/093224.753407:WARNING:controller_impl.cc(1190)] Background download complete, client: 6, completion type: 0, file size:4951
[1367400:1367400:1030/093224.857765:WARNING:controller_impl.cc(1190)] Background download complete, client: 6, completion type: 0, file size:9419
[1367400:1367400:1030/093228.584823:WARNING:controller_impl.cc(1190)] Background download complete, client: 6, completion type: 0, file size:34864416
[1367400:1367400:1030/093408.850017:WARNING:pref_notifier_impl.cc(41)] Pref observer for media_router.cast_allow_all_ips found at shutdown.
```

The Version of Chrome is

```
google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119
```

On another page I found the flag `--no-sandbox`.
When I use this flag to start chrome, it is working.

Is there a way to permanently set this flag inside the settings?
When using the flag I can go to the settings and see it is disabled. When I not using the flag I am not able to open the settings too disable it.

- Is there a way to fix the problem when running without this flag?

Comment: Did you try "incognito" mode? Did you try running Chrome with another Ubuntu user?

Comment: yes and yes. The problems remains the same :-(